# Using Xamarin for iOs, Android and Windows Phone

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, windows-phone

I just have a question regarding the use of Xamarin. When making an app for iOS, how similar is it when making it for Android and Windows Phone?
The code changes somehow ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two general approaches to doing this:

first, using Xamarin Classic/Platform, you would write separate UI for each platform you're supporting, but use shared libraries for non-UI code (data, business logic, services, etc).

alternatively, you can use Xamarin Forms.  XF allows you to write a single UI layer that is used by each platform, as well as the same shared library approach for backend code that Classic does.  XF allows for customization per-platform in a variety of ways.

Xamarin has numerous samples of using both approaches on their website.